# How do I use element-wise operation in org-tables (orgmode)

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have this table, and I want to do the following:
For an element a(i,j) of the table, it's value is the product of the last element in the row(i) times the last element in the column(j), divided by the last element in the matrix (i_max,j_max)

What I have tried so far, to get an idea of where I'm at:

[image: Org-mode table]

Comment: Olá Pedro. Can you edit your question and add the table as text instead of an image? So we can copy and work on your data. You can paste the table text, select and press the code button in the editor.

Comment: Sorry for not putting it in plain text!

Thank you for the answer

Comment: If the answer has answered your question, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need:

1. `@>`, or `@>$0` refers to the last row, current column.
2. `$>`, or `@0$>` refers to the current row, last column.
3. `@>$>` refers to the last cell in the table.

Documentation [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#References).

```
| C1    |        C2 |        C3 |        C4 | 5 | C6   |
|-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---+------|
| sp    | 157.09091 | 264.88201 | 143.30368 |   | 648  |
| pr    | 72.969697 | 123.03933 | 66.565442 |   | 301  |
| rs    | 145.93939 | 246.07866 | 133.13088 |   | 602  |
|-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---+------|
| total |       376 |       634 |       343 |   | 1551 |
#+TBLFM: @5$6=vsum(@I..@II)::@2$2..@4$4=@0$>*@>$0/@>$>
```